# Python Styling DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-styles

I am trying to style a df before saving it to Excel.
The idea is to style a column called "Date PI" which I have already converted to datetime when that date as already passed. The function that should do that is called "color". I notice that the function is not even called. What am I doing wrong?

```
def generate_report_all():
    update_company_perf_on_ships()
    .....
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Report.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter', date_format='yyyy-mm-dd', datetime_format='yyyy-mm-dd')
    df3['Last Inspection'] = pd.to_datetime(df3['Last Inspection'].astype('datetime64[ns]'))
    df3['Date PI'] = pd.to_datetime(df3['Date PI'].astype('datetime64[ns]'))
    df3['Date PII'] = pd.to_datetime(df3['Date PII'].astype('datetime64[ns]'))

    def color(val):
        if val < datetime.now():
            return 'background-color: %s' % 'red'

    df3.style.applymap(color, subset=['Date PI'])

    df3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Report Paris', index=False)
    writer.save()
    os.system("open -a 'Microsoft Excel.app' 'Report.xlsx'")
```

Bottom line question is why the "color" function is not having an effect at all. not even called.
Thank you very much everyone.

Comment: That's a lot of codes with no data. You should really consider narrowing down your code and adding sample data/expected output.

Comment: Sure, thank you @QuangHoang

Comment: The problem is that `df3.style.applymap(color, subset=['Date PI'])` returns a styler. It does not alter `df3`. You need to save the `styler` -> `styler = df3.style.applymap(color, subset=['Date PI'])` Then use `styler.to_excel(...)` instead.

Comment: Will test it out. Thank you very much @HenryEcker

Comment: I can't guarantee that that styling function (as written) will work or not, but minimally you'll be able to call the function. I assume you'll get a truth value of a series is ambiguous error but I can't say for sure without a runnable code snippet with sample input.

Comment: @HenryEcker thank you very much. Your support was valuable and useful!